# ruby with gem devise autofill in field fullname

Tags: ruby, devise

My code is :
users_controller.rb

```
**class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
       @user.create(user_params)
      if @user.save
          @user.fullname = @user.firstname + ‘ ‘ + @user.lastname
      end
  end
end**
```

user.rb code :

```
**class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :lname, presence:true, length: {maximum: 40}
  validates :fname, presence:true, length: {maximum: 40}
  validates :fullname, presence:true, length: {maximum: 80}
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/assets/default_image.jpeg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  has_many :rooms
end**
```

And

new.html.erb code :

```
**
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/devise_errors' %>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.text_field :lname, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Prénom" %>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.text_field :fname, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Nom de famille" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :fullname, autofocus: true,  class: "form-control", placeholder: "Nom complet ( Prénom + Nom)" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">**
```

I would like that when user fill in lname and fname fields, fullname will be automatically fill in with lname + ' ' +fname.

Thanks for your help

Comment: for be more clear in my form I have 3 fields First nane (fname), last name (lname) and full name which should be fname+lname

Answer (score 1):

in the form, just let user fill firstname and lastname, delete the fullname text_field. auto generate and save fullname in the backend.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user_params[:fullname] = "#{user_params[:firstname]} #{user_params[:lastname]}"
    @user.create(user_params)
  end
end
```